# trigger collection 'ready' event after each model's setup logic

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events

I have collection representing a tree. Each model have parent attribute that becomes from server as id. After resetting collection with incoming data, each model have to find its parent in collection and set reference as attribute instead of plain id. After that there must be a one event triggered from collection that it is ready for rendering.

```
var node = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        //reset event fired after all models are in collection,
        //so we can setup relations
        this.collection.on('reset', this.setup, this);
    },
    setup: function(){
        this.set('parent', this.collection.get(this.get('parent')));
        this.trigger('ready', this);//-->to collection event aggregator?
    }
});
var tree = Backbone.Collection.extend({model: node})
```

Is there any clean way to see all models done with its setup? Or I have to write custom event aggregator in collection?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, what you want is to bind `reset` event in `Collection` rather than in `Model`.

```
var Node = Backbone.Model.extend({

}),

Tree = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Node,
    initialize: function() {
        this.on('reset', this.setup, this);
    },
    setup: function() {
        this.each(this.updateModel, this);
        //Here you have all your models setup
    },
    updateModel: function(m) {
        m.set({
            parent: this.get(m.get('parent'));
        });
    }
})
```